# Tool for viewing structural xib differences?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, diff, xib

Is there a diff tool for viewing differences in XIB's? It could display what graphical elements are in one xib while missing in other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a tool that will do this visually. Only textual comparison is currently possible (diff, FileMerge, etc.) which is still a big advantage over the older nib format.

Answer (score 1):

XIB files are regular XML files. You can diff them using your favorite diff tool.

Comment: my favorite diff tool shows only textual, but not visual differences. After all - each element has it's own unique ID which means that EVERY element will be different from it's counterpart in other document.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that is a problem. I have never seen a visual tool for diffing XIB files. :-(

Comment: There's no way to determine equality or differences between two files with different IDs in them. In the case of three or more windows (for example) between the xibs, how would you know which two windows to compare?

Comment: comparison should be done on two windows. and i think it should be more of a hierarchical differences (views -> subviews recursion) thingie.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter both through nib2objc (http://github.com/akosma/nib2objc) and then compare the results. It will then show you the differences in code.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but it crashed when processing one of my xib files. Your mileage may vary.